# FTP command works in Excel VBA but not PowerPoint

Tags: vba, excel, ftp, powerpoint

In my excel VBA code I'm automating the process of running a script ("PULLSCRIPT", which is also created in the code) that runs `ftp`, opens my FTP address, enters my user and password, pulls a file using `mget`, and lastly moves that file to another folder using Name. It works in Excel VBA (I click a macro and it does all these steps, no manual input required), but when I copy and paste it to PowerPoint VBA, the line

```
Shell ("ftp -s:" & sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME)
```

doesn't run. It doesn't give me an error and, F8 stepping through it, it looks like the shell opens (just like when I step through it in Excel), but it never runs PULLSCRIPT (or if it does then it's not working). When I manually open `cmd` and run the PULLSCRIPT it works, but the point of automating it was so people wouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug the command execution, add `cmd /k` in front of it:

```
Shell ("cmd /k ftp -s:" & ...)
```

This way, the console window stays open and you can see, what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Somehow, the Shell command was running PULLSCRIPT in another directory, so I added ChDir "C:\correct path" and it works!!